# Ubuntu upgrade problem Xenial to Zesty [solved]

Tags: boot, upgrade, encryption

I recently decided I needed to upgrade from Xenial (Filezilla had stopped working). I thought I would go to Yaketty Yak but ended up with Zesty Zapus.

I use disk encryption. The problem I have is that now Ubuntu just hangs after password entry to decrypt the disk. I get "*sda5_crypt set up successfully*", and the moving dots splash screen - then nothing.

If  I interrupt the boot process and select 4.10.0-28 recovery mode, then I can get the system to boot. But just selecting "4.10.0-28 generic" or "4.10.0-28 upstart" does not work.

I have noted a number of errors/warnings on screen:

> /proc/self/fd/9:28 /proc/self/fd/9:  /etc/init.d/rcS not found
>   warning failed to connect to lvmetad
>   volume group 'ubuntu-vg' not found

I have used Ubuntu for several years without any problems. So I'm not used to this! Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

**Update**

What I know is that I can boot from recovery mode. I think that's probably setting a non-controversial display driver option, so maybe that's my clue.

My VGA is integrated Intel:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

After boot in recovery mode, I see:

```
$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 4.0, 256 bits)
```

In System Settings >> Software Updates >> Additional Drivers I only see  "Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from intel-microcode (proprietory)". Whether I enable or disable this, the problem remains.

So right now I'm thinking I need a driver for my VGA. Or then again, perhaps I'm barking up the wrong tree...

**Another update**

I tried this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Unfortunately no improvement. Stuck now...

Comment: I have been most impressed by the stylistic improvements made by 3rd parties to my post. But still looking for a substantive contribution please!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not a display driver issue. Instead it was because /etc/fstab used names instead of UUIDs.

The clue was in the boot log which showed things on the lines of "**A start job is running for /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root**" (and others).